# Display calendar using a loop

Tags: c, datetime, homework, formatting

Desired output:

[image: screenshot]
[image: screenshot]

Can I get an shorter version of this code? My instructor just wants me to figure it out my self.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int month,week,day;

    printf("Enter month: ");
    scanf("%d",&month);
    printf("[ 1=Sunday  2=Monday 3=Tuesday 4=Wednesday ]\n[      5=Thursday 6=Friday 7=Saturday      ]\n");
    printf("Enter starting day of the week: ");
    scanf("%d",&week);

        if (week==1 && month>0 && month<=12)
            if (month == 1 || month == 3 || month ==5 || month ==7 || month ==8 || month == 10 || month ==12)
            for (day=1;day<=31;day++)
                if (day==7 || day==14 || day==21 || day==28)
                printf("%3d\n",day);
                else
                printf("%3d",day);
            else if (month ==4 || month==6 || month ==9 ||month==11 )
            for (day=1;day<=30;day++)
                if (day==7 || day==14 || day==21 || day==28)
                printf("%3d\n",day);
                else
                printf("%3d",day);
            else
            for (day=1;day<=29;day++)
                if (day==7 || day==14 || day==21 || day==28)
                printf("%3d\n",day);
                else
                printf("%3d",day);

        else if (week==2 && month>0 && month<=12)
            if (month == 1 || month == 3 || month ==5 || month ==7 || month ==8 || month == 10 || month ==12)
            for (day=1;day<=31;day++)
                if (day==6 || day==13 || day==20 || day==27)
                printf("%3d\n",day);
                else if (day==1)
                printf("   %3d",day);
                else
                printf("%3d",day);
            else if (month ==4 || month==6 || month ==9 ||month==11 )
            for (day=1;day<=30;day++)
                if (day==6 || day==13 || day==20 || day==27)
                printf("%3d\n",day);
                else if (day==1)
                printf("   %3d",day);
                else
                printf("%3d",day);
            else
            for (day=1;day<=29;day++)
                if (day==6 || day==13 || day==20 || day==27)
                printf("%3d\n",day);
                else if (day==1)
                printf("   %3d",day);
                else
                printf("%3d",day);

        else if (week==3 && month>0 && month<=12)
            if (month == 1 || month == 3 || month ==5 || month ==7 || month ==8 || month == 10 || month ==12)
            for (day=1;day<=31;day++)
                if (day==5 || day==12 || day==19 || day==26)
                printf("%3d\n",day);
                else if (day==1)
                printf("      %3d",day);
                else
                printf("%3d",day);
            else if (month ==4 || month==6 || month ==9 ||month==11 )
            for (day=1;day<=30;day++)
                if (day==5 || day==12 || day==19 || day==26)
                printf("%3d\n",day);
                else if (day==1)
                printf("      %3d",day);
                else
                printf("%3d",day);
            else
            for (day=1;day<=29;day++)
                if (day==5 || day==12 || day==19 || day==26)
                printf("%3d\n",day);
                else if (day==1)
                printf("      %3d",day);
                else
                printf("%3d",day);

        else if (week==4 && month>0 && month<=12)
            if (month == 1 || month == 3 || month ==5 || month ==7 || month ==8 || month == 10 || month ==12)
            for (day=1;day<=31;day++)
                if (day==4 || day==11 || day==18 || day==25)
                printf("%3d\n",day);
                else if (day==1)
                printf("         %3d",day);
                else
                printf("%3d",day);
            else if (month ==4 || month==6 || month ==9 ||month==11 )
            for (day=1;day<=30;day++)
                if (day==4 || day==11 || day==18 || day==25)
                printf("%3d\n",day);
                else if (day==1)
                printf("         %3d",day);
                else
                printf("%3d",day);
            else
            for (day=1;day<=29;day++)
                if (day==4 || day==11 || day==18 || day==25)
                printf("%3d\n",day);
                else if (day==1)
                printf("         %3d",day);
                else
                printf("%3d",day);


        else if (week==5 && month>0 && month<=12)
            if (month == 1 || month == 3 || month ==5 || month ==7 || month ==8 || month == 10 || month ==12)
            for (day=1;day<=31;day++)
                if (day==3 || day==10 || day==17 || day==24 || day==31)
                printf("%3d\n",day);
                else if (day==1)
                printf("            %3d",day);
                else
                printf("%3d",day);
            else if (month ==4 || month==6 || month ==9 ||month==11 )
            for (day=1;day<=30;day++)
                if (day==3 || day==10 || day==17 || day==24)
                printf("%3d\n",day);
                else if (day==1)
                printf("            %3d",day);
                else
                printf("%3d",day);
            else
            for (day=1;day<=29;day++)
                if (day==3 || day==10 || day==17 || day==24)
                printf("%3d\n",day);
                else if (day==1)
                printf("            %3d",day);
                else
                printf("%3d",day);

        else if (week==6 && month>0 && month<=12)
            if (month == 1 || month == 3 || month ==5 || month ==7 || month ==8 || month == 10 || month ==12)
            for (day=1;day<=31;day++)
                if (day==2 || day==9 || day==16 || day==23 || day==30)
                printf("%3d\n",day);
                else if (day==1)
                printf("               %3d",day);
                else
                printf("%3d",day);
            else if (month ==4 || month==6 || month ==9 ||month==11)
            for (day=1;day<=30;day++)
                if (day==2 || day==9 || day==16 || day==23 || day==30)
                printf("%3d\n",day);
                else if (day==1)
                printf("               %3d",day);
                else
                printf("%3d",day);
            else
            for (day=1;day<=29;day++)
                if (day==2 || day==9 || day==16 || day==23)
                printf("%3d\n",day);
                else if (day==1)
                printf("               %3d",day);
                else
                printf("%3d",day);

        else if (week==7 && month>0 && month<=12)
            if (month == 1 || month == 3 || month ==5 || month ==7 || month ==8 || month == 10 || month ==12)
            for (day=1;day<=31;day++)
                if (day==8 || day==15 || day==22 || day==29)
                printf("%3d\n",day);
                else if (day==1)
                printf("                  %3d\n",day);
                else
                printf("%3d",day);
            else if (month ==4 || month==6 || month ==9 ||month==11 )
            for (day=1;day<=30;day++)
                if (day==8 || day==15 || day==22 || day==29)
                printf("%3d\n",day);
                else if (day==1)
                printf("                  %3d\n",day);
                else
                printf("%3d",day);
            else
            for (day=1;day<=29;day++)
                if (day==8 || day==15 || day==22 || day==29)
                printf("%3d\n",day);
                else if (day==1)
                printf("                  %3d\n",day);
                else
                printf("%3d",day);

        else printf("Invalid Input!");

    getch();
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! This question is incomplete. To help reviewers give you better answers, please add sufficient context to your question. The more you tell us about what your code does and what the purpose of doing that is, the easier it will be for reviewers to help you. See also [this meta question](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1226/code-should-include-a-description-of-what-the-code-does).

Comment: If your instructor wants you to figure it out yourself, it's unlikely your instructor actually meant "ask people on the internet."

Answer (score 3):

### Avoid repetitions of code

Whenever you repeat your code you need to look into whether it can simplified. The key thing to look for is where does the copied code blocks differ, and can you extract those differences into variables or similar.

In your case this should be rather simple, as what varies is the major loop counter, i.e. `28(/29)`, `30` or `31`. In addition you need to know which day of the week you're starting on, and when to add the newlines.

The latter can be approached using the modulo operator, `% 7`, with a proper offset related to the day of week.

### Some style comments

Here are also some style comments related to your code:

- *Use braces around blocks of `for` and `if`* – All of your code relies heavily on using single statements for all of your `for` and `if` blocks. This is somewhat dangerous, and you should *always* use braces arounds blocks to be safe.

  This in addition to using proper indentation for each new code level, i.e. `for` and `if` would make your code a lot more readable and better to understand. This would also help you eliminate some bugs, which are very likely to occur at some point in time.
- *Be precise in variable naming* – Instead of `week`, use something like `starting_weekday` (or `weekday`). Having precise variable names will help you when your programs evolve and get more complicated. Having unclear variable names, will obfuscate the meaning of your program and make it harder to write correct logic.
- *Add spaces around operators* – Instead of `for (day=1;day<=29;day++)`, add a space around the operators, making it `for (day = 1; day <= 29; day++)`. This is yet another tip which makes your code easier to understand, and helps you avoid bugs and features later on. So add spaces after commas, and around operators.

More could be said, but this should get you going on implementing a much nicer and cleaner version of your code in a lot less lines.

Answer (score 2):

You have 3 × 7 cases, which is a lot. One better approach would be to print the desired number of blanks, like the code in [this question](/q/119669/9357).

For handling the month lengths, it would be better to use a lookup table instead of so many `if` statements, like [this](/a/102653/9357).